# simple slow stochastics strategy

Tags: pine-script

### Issues and What I tried

I am studying pinescript for trading view to backtest my strategy and trying simple strategy (only for long) with slow stochastics as an example.

If %K crossover %D, then long entry should be done at the next bar. Otherwise(if %K crossnuder %D), the position shall be exited at the next bar.

For entry, it works but exit does not work.

I already checked the documentation about strategy.entry() and strategy.exit().

https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/strategy-exit-function/

https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/strategy-entry-function/

Here is my script.

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Slow Stochastics Crossover", overlay=true,
     pyramiding=0, initial_capital=100000,
     commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order,
     commission_value=4, slippage=2)


smoothK = input.int(3, minval=1), smoothD = input.int(3, minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, 14), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)

atrLen     = input.int(14, title="ATR Length")
atrValue = ta.atr(atrLen)
stopOffset = input.float(2, title="Stop Offset Multiple", step=.25)
profitOffset = input.float(3, title="Stop Offset Multiple", step=.25)

enterLong = ta.crossover(k, d)
exitLong = ta.crossunder(k, d)

longProfit =  close + (profitOffset * atrValue)

longStop = 0.0
longStop := enterLong ? close - (stopOffset * atrValue) :
     longStop[1]


// Position sizing inputs
usePosSize  = input.bool(true, title="Use Position Sizing?")
maxRisk     = input.float(2, title="Max Position Risk %", step=.25)
maxExposure = input.float(10, title="Max Position Exposure %", step=1)
marginPerc  = input.int(10, title="Margin %")

riskEquity = (maxRisk * 0.01) * strategy.equity
riskTrade  = (atrValue * stopOffset) * syminfo.pointvalue

maxPos = ((maxExposure * 0.01) * strategy.equity) /
     ((marginPerc * 0.01) * (close * syminfo.pointvalue))

posSize = usePosSize ? math.min(math.floor(riskEquity / riskTrade), maxPos) : 1

plot(k, color=color.orange, title="Fast SMA")
plot(d, color=color.teal, linewidth=2, title="Slow SMA")

plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? longStop : na, color=color.green, 
     linewidth=2, style=plot.style_circles)


if enterLong
    strategy.entry("EL", strategy.long, qty=posSize, stop=longStop)
    strategy.exit("XL", from_entry="EL", stop=longStop)

if exitLong
    strategy.exit("XL", from_entry="EL", limit=longProfit)
```

### Outcome

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You shouldn't use multiple `strategy.exit()`s for TP ad SL. The last one will modify the first one. You can combine both of them in a single `strategy.exit()`.
2. You want to close your position conditionally whenever that `crossunder()` event happens. In that case, you should use `strategy.close()` and not `strategy.exit().

Below change will do:

```
if enterLong
    strategy.entry("EL", strategy.long, qty=posSize, stop=longStop)
    strategy.exit("XL", from_entry="EL", stop=longStop, limit=longProfit)

if exitLong
    strategy.close("EL")
```